# How to change height of slider control in windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

It must be simple but I can't figure it out. How to change the height of slider control in windows phone? No matter how large value I set for `Height` it remains as it is

```
<Slider Width="100" Height="600" />
```

[image]

Comment: What WP sdk version are you using?

Comment: Try setting it in MinHeight as opposed to Height. Actually I don't know whether it's MinHeight or Minimum. try both

Comment: @RachelGallen same result

Comment: have you got the rowdefinition set in xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the page in Expression Blend

1. Right click on Slider Control on Page .
2. Select Edit Template and Select Edit Current/ Edit a copy as you wish.
3. Change width values in Scale sub tab of Render Tab   for the properties *HorizontalTrack, HorizontalFill,HorizontalThumb* in Expression Blend
   and you will see the difference.

Save the page and get back to Visual Studio and your custom template will be added to page resources.

*I have attached the image for Expression Blend .*

[image]

And the result will be like

[image]

Template code :- which might be of help for you.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PhoneSimpleRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="SliderStyle1" TargetType="Slider">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalFill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform ScaleY="2.9"/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrack" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,50" Opacity="0.2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform ScaleY="2.9"/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalTrackLargeChangeDecreaseRepeatButton" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource PhoneSimpleRepeatButton}"/>
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalTrackLargeChangeIncreaseRepeatButton" Grid.Column="2" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource PhoneSimpleRepeatButton}"/>
                        <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Grid.Column="1" Height="12" Margin="0,22,0,50" Width="12" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform ScaleY="4.65"/>
                            </Thumb.RenderTransform>
                            <Thumb.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Canvas Background="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Height="12" Width="12">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Height="84" IsHitTestVisible="True" Canvas.Left="-24" Canvas.Top="-22" Width="60"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Thumb.Template>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And usage it in control like:-

```
 <Slider Margin="0,49,56,348" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="360" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}" />
```